# Subclass table mapping in nHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, subclass

Firstly, sorry about the wall of text.

I have the following schema. Note that `User_Contact` may contain a null in `ContactID`.

[image: Schema]

At the class level it is then implemented in the following way

```
public abstract class User : EntityBase<Guid>, IAggregateRoot
{
    public User()
    {

    }

    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }

    protected abstract override void Validate();
}

public class SiteUser : User
{
    public SiteUser() { }

    public virtual Guid ApplicationId { get; set; }
    public virtual string UserName { get; set; }
    public virtual string LoweredUserName { get; set; }
    public virtual string MobileAlias { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsAnonymous { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime LastActivityDate { get; set; }

    protected override void Validate()
    { 
        if (this.ApplicationId == Guid.Empty)
            base.AddBrokenRule(UserBusinessRules.ApplicationIdRequired);

        if (this.UserName.IsNullOrEmpty())
            base.AddBrokenRule(UserBusinessRules.UserNameRequired);

        if (this.LoweredUserName.IsNullOrEmpty())
            base.AddBrokenRule(UserBusinessRules.LoweredUserNameRequired);

        if (this.LastActivityDate == DateTime.MinValue)
            base.AddBrokenRule(UserBusinessRules.LastActivityDateRequired);

    }
}

public class SiteContact : SiteUser
{

    public SiteContact() 
    {
    }


    public virtual int ExternalID { get; set; }
    //All the rest...

    protected override void Validate()
    { 
        //validate
    }
}
```

So basically the idea is that every single `SiteContact` is a `SiteUser` but not every `SiteUser` is a `SiteContact`.

Where I have gotten completely stuck is how on earth to map this relationship in nHibernate. I seem to be able to retrieve a `SiteUser` but unable to retrieve a `SiteContact` and it is clear why. The mapping that I have implemented results in the following sql being executed.

```
SELECT this_.userid             AS UserId18_0_, 
       this_.firstname          AS FirstName18_0_, 
       this_.lastname           AS LastName18_0_, 
       //Blah blah.....
FROM   user_contact this_ 
       INNER JOIN contact this_1_ 
               ON this_.userid = this_1_.contactid  //Here is the error this should be ContactID = ContactID
       INNER JOIN aspnet_users this_2_ 
               ON this_.userid = this_2_.userid 
WHERE  ( CASE 
           WHEN this_.contactid IS NOT NULL THEN 1 
           ELSE 0 
         END ) = '1'
```

But I can't for the life of me work out how to fix this problem in my hbm mapping file. Here is the file with some fields omitted for simplicity.

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="MyProject.Namespaces.Model.Entities" assembly="MyProject.Namespaces.Model">


  <class name="User" table="User_Contact" lazy="true" abstract="true">

    <id name="ID" column="UserId" type="guid">
      <generator class="guid" />
    </id>

    <discriminator column="ContactID" formula="(CASE WHEN ContactID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)" />

    <property name="FirstName">
      <column name="FirstName" sql-type="nvarchar(500)" not-null="true" />
    </property>

    <property name="LastName">
      <column name="LastName" sql-type="nvarchar(500)" not-null="true" />
    </property>

    <subclass name="SiteContact" discriminator-value="1">
      <join table="Contact">
        <key column="ContactID" /> //I assume the problem is here. I have tried adding foreign-key="ContactID" to no success

        <property name="ExternalID" insert="false" update="false">
          <column name="ExternalID" sql-type="int" not-null="true" />
        </property>

        //The rest of the mapped columns

      </join>
      <join table="aspnet_Users">
        <key column="UserId" />

        <property name="ApplicationId">
          <column name="ApplicationId" sql-type="guid" not-null="true" />
        </property>

        <property name="UserName">
          <column name="UserName" sql-type="nvarchar(256)" not-null="true" />
        </property>

        <property name="LoweredUserName">
          <column name="LoweredUserName" sql-type="nvarchar(256)" not-null="true" />
        </property>

        <property name="MobileAlias">
          <column name="MobileAlias" sql-type="nvarchar(16)" not-null="false" />
        </property>

        <property name="IsAnonymous">
          <column name="IsAnonymous" sql-type="bit" not-null="true" />
        </property>

        <property name="LastActivityDate">
          <column name="LastActivityDate" sql-type="datetime" not-null="true" />
        </property>

      </join>
    </subclass>

    <subclass name="SiteUser" discriminator-value="0">
      <join table="aspnet_Users">
        <key column="UserId" />

        //blah blah blah

      </join>
    </subclass>

  </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

Hopefully someone could please tell me if I am even on the right track about this mapping and perhaps provide some guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a pretty convoluted way of mapping it.  I'm not sure what benefits you're hoping to achieve from using inheritence in this situation, and I would suggest using composition instead (ie. having a class per table and mapping the relationships).

Having said that, you presumably have your reasons, so I would suggest the following to achieve what I think you want:

1. Map your SiteUser class as the base class and use a join from User_Contact to aspnet_Users (so don't have User as the base in the mapping)
2. Map your SiteContact then as a subclass using the joined-subclass mapping instead of the subclass so you don't need to use discriminators.

Comment: Actually you were pretty much on the right track, we did have our reasons for why we wanted to take this approach but in the end decided that it was exactly as you say "Too convoluted". So we ended up restructuring the schema as a result. Having said that, I was still curious as to how to achieve this mapping and it appears that your solution would work. Thank you very much.